# PowerShell & Mediawiki - Unable to get CSRF Token

Tags: powershell, mediawiki-api

I'm preparing a powershell script to bulk edit mediawiki pages but I have some problem with the csrf-token, the only value that is returned is "+\", what I'm missing ?

Code written so far:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web

$protocol = 'http://'
$wiki = '10.10.10.95/'
$api = 'api.php'
$username = 'BotUser'
$password = 'BotPass'

$csrftoken
$websession
$wikiversion

function Get-CsrfToken()
{
    if($csrftoken -eq $null)
    {
        $uri = $protocol + $wiki + $api

        if((Get-Version) -lt '1.24')
        {
            $uri = $protocol + $wiki + $api

            $body = @{}
            $body.action = 'query'
            $body.format = 'json'
            $body.prop = 'info'
            $body.intoken = 'edit'
            $body.titles = 'User:' + $username

            $object = Invoke-WebRequest $uri -Method Get -Body $body -WebSession (Get-WebSession)
            $json = $object.Content
            $object = ConvertFrom-Json $json

            $pages = $object.query.pages
            $page = ($pages | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty).Name
            $csrftoken = $pages.($page).edittoken
        }
        else
        {
            $body = @{}
            $body.action = 'query'
            $body.format = 'json'
            $body.meta = 'tokens'
            $body.type = 'csrf'

            $object = Invoke-WebRequest $uri -Method Get -Body $body -WebSession (Get-WebSession)
            $json = $object.Content
            $object = ConvertFrom-Json $json

            $csrftoken = $object.query.tokens.csrftoken
        }
    }

    return $csrftoken
}

function Edit-Page($title, $summary, $text)
{
    $uri = $protocol + $wiki + $api

    $body = @{}
    $body.action = 'edit'
    $body.format = 'json'
    $body.bot = ''
    $body.title = $title
    $body.summary = $summary
    $body.text = $text
    $body.token = Get-CsrfToken

    $object = Invoke-WebRequest $uri -Method Post -Body $body -WebSession (Get-WebSession)
    $json = $object.Content
    $object = ConvertFrom-Json $json

    if($object.edit.result -ne 'Success')
    {
        throw('Error editing page:' + $object + ',' + $object.error)
    }
}

#Show Token
Get-CsrfToken

#Test
Edit-Page "Test_Page" "Bot Updated" "Page content goes here.."
```

Here is the returned error:

```
Get-Member : You must specify an object for the Get-Member cmdlet.
In C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Mediawiki.ps1:35 char:31
 + ... $page = ($pages | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty).Name
 + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo : CloseError: (:) [Get-Member], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoObjectInGetMember,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetMemberCommand
```

Useful information:

- Mediawiki's version is the latest stable 1.39.3
- PowerShell version is: 5.1
- The wiki is configured with the **$wgGroupPermissions['*']['read'] = false;** in the **LocalSettings.php** so the wiki is "private" (an account is needed).
- If I remove **$wgGroupPermissions['*']['read'] = false;** the test page page is created correctly (I believe that the change is made as an anonymous user due to the lack of token)

Comment: Either $pages is empty or you need to get one item from the array : $page = ($pages | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty)[0].Name

Comment: I really have no idea what it could be, this morning I relaunched the script and it ran on the first try

Comment: Old token expired so you were able to get a new token.

Comment: Indeed it is a cogent explanation, if you convert the comment into an answer I flag it as accepted solution. Thanks again!